# How to get all files from all subfolders in a vscode web extension?

Tags: javascript, directory, vscode-extensions, subdirectory

I have written a VS Code **web** extension for unzipping .zip files, and I'm trying to add the ability to create zip files given a folder. However, I cannot figure out how to reliably get all files from all subfolders of user-selected folder, add them to JSZip, and then run `JSZip.generateAsync`. **How can I get all files from all subfolders, and when that is done run other code?**

Something I've tried is writing a recursive function which does the following. (pseudo-code)

```
Parameter: URI
Get folder from URI using vscode.workspace.fs.readDirectory()
  .then(
    for (each in files) {
      if (files[each][1] === 1) { // file
        vscode.workspace.fs.readFile(vscode.Uri.joinPath(URI, files[each][0])).then( /* add to JSZip */ )
      } else if (files[each][1] === 2) { //directory
        call self with vscode.Uri.joinPath(URI, files[each][0])
      }
    }
  )
```

You can see full code [here](https://github.com/AdamRaichu/vscode-zip-viewer/tree/eaf12673414f5f3316da44ac25cc69a0f1e3f251).

See [FileSystem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystem)

Comment: And that function you wrote did not do what you want? What was the problem?

Comment: It did get all the files, but I wasn't able to detect when it was complete.